# merge mutliple files into single file, new file file should merge to new line in output file

Tags: python-3.x

I've written script to merge multiple files into single file and create list from that.

requirement: file1 + file2 = file3 like below

file1 :

```
37717531209
201128307083
211669759863
496338947094
```

File 2:

```
348353447295
278262427715
901601149752
333676465561
```

my outputfile(not expecting this output):

```
37717531209
201128307083
211669759863
496338947094348353447295
278262427715
901601149752
333676465561
```

my expected outputfile:

```
37717531209
201128307083
211669759863
496338947094
348353447295
278262427715
901601149752
333676465561
```

My code is:

```
     with open(outputfile, 'wb') as outfile:
        for filename in glob.glob('*.accts'):
            if filename == outputfile:
            # don't want to copy the output into the output
                continue
            with open(filename, 'rb') as readfile:
                shutil.copyfileobj(readfile, outfile)
                #accounts = list(outfile)
with open('accounts.txt') as f:
    acc = list(f)
    accounts = []
    for element in acc:
        accounts.append(element.strip())
```

I want the new file to merge from next line. not to start from same line.

Comment: One option would be to read all the file contents into a list and join it with `\n` and then write it to `outfile`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [append contents from one file to another with newline separation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20607661/append-contents-from-one-file-to-another-with-newline-separation)

Comment: Based on that link, I think you just need to add something like `outfile.write(os.linesep)` after your `shutil.copyfileobj` call...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't appear to be doing anything that would require writing the contents of the input files into an output file. At the end, after creating the output file, you reopen it and process the account numbers it contains. You could simply do this, which requires no output file at all:

```
accounts = []
for filename in glob.glob('*.accts'):
    with open(filename) as readfile:
        accounts.extend(line.strip() for line in readfile)
return accounts
```

Furthermore, you could probably do away with downloading the *.accts files
by using [`download_fileobj()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-example-download-file.html#downloading-files) to download the files into a file like object (e.g. a `io.BytesIO` object) and processing from there.